# Icicles showing user-error message in echo area during TAB-completion

Tags: fonts, faces, completion, echo-area, icicles

i have a strange behaviour of my emacs (25.1.1) running in cygwin within a terminal window (mintty 2.7.3). Every time when doing TAB-competion (eg. M-x describe-func) I got following messages in the echo area:"user-error: Cannot decrease the default face height more than it already is". I can not debug that kind of error, because it is an user-error. All modifications, which are related to "set-face-attribute" were commented one by one and new reloaded. I already tried to set debug-ignored-erros to nil, but no success.

After a bit research:
I am using **icicles** and i found out it has something to do with the face configuration of icicles completion menu. The hook which narrow down the selecetion appropiately to user input kicks that user-error in the echo area by pressing TAB-key.
But setting all faces used in that completion menu to a high value of 110pt doesn't gave me the result.

After a bit more research:
Setting in **icicles** icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag or icicle-incremental-completion to t for having an ido-completion feeling then the icicle command completion combined with the output of above mentioned user-error message every time you extend your input (no TAB-Key) makes icicles in that way useless. By the way the error message has changed with these settings to "icicle-execute-extended-command: Cannot decrease the default face height more than it already is", but any way it means the same.

For any hints, background information I would be very thankful.
Falk

Comment: If you want to do some grepping to track down the problem, the function `text-scale-increase` is generating the error message.

Comment: Thanks "lawlist" for your hint. I solved the problem and found a constant in icicles-opt.el with name "icicle-Completions-text-scale-decrease". Setting it to 0.0 stopped that annoying message in the echo area.